# Regarding the Python library Panel, how can I get panels to dynamically update?

Tags: python, chatbot, panel

I'm trying to get a chatbot output panel to show streaming output first and when streaming is complete, have that panel update to show completed answer. The idea is that every time a new query is entered, the object that streams will be displayed only until it is finished streaming, in which case it will be replaced by the completed answer.

In the below example, I need panels to update as soon as a query is entered, and again after the streaming is complete. Instead, they will only update when the final return statement is reached.

(With this approach, panels pertaining to new QA pairs are added above old ones)

```
 def conversation_chain(self, query=None):

    if not query:
        return pn.WidgetBox(pn.Row('User:', pn.pane.Markdown("", width=600)), pn.Row('Bot:', 'No query entered'), scroll=True)

    """ In the case that query is passed, we need panels to update immediately, but they don't of course """
    
    self.bot_message_panel.object = ''

    preliminary_panels = [ 
        pn.Row('User:', pn.pane.Markdown(query, width=600)),
        pn.Row('Chatbot:', self.bot_message_panel),
        pn.Spacer(height=50)
    ] 

    for panel in reversed(preliminary_panels):
        self.panels.insert(0, panel)
    
    for next_token in self.stream(query, self.chat_history): # streaming happens here
        self.bot_message_panel.object += next_token

    self.streamed_answers.append(self.bot_message_panel.object)

    most_recent_answer = self.streamed_answers[self.query_count]


    """
    Now that streaming is complete, we want to replace the streamed content with 
    completed answer. 

    """

    completed_answer_panel = pn.Row('completed_answer:', pn.pane.Markdown(most_recent_answer, width=600))
    self.panels.insert(2, completed_answer)  # Inserting the 'completed_answer' panel at index 2, after User and bot panels.
    self.panels.pop(1)  # Remove the 'bot' panel from the list.
   
   
    result = pn.WidgetBox(*self.panels,scroll=True) # The only update as of now
    return result
```